# How to convert numbers in swift language from English to Arabic

Tags: swift

I am writing at the moment an application to calculate BMI which has two sliders, one for hight and one for weight, when the user slide it to the left or right, I will update the label above the slider to show the number in arabic, but I cannot find a way or a method in Swift that convert english number to arabic number, the english number I have right now are three decimal places (for hight) like 1.84 meter, I want to find a way to convert all the three char from english to Arabic

When I use the below code, the output always 0.00 in storyboard

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var highetDisplay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weightDisplay: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func highetSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {

    highetDisplay.text = String(format: "%.2f", getNumerals(num: sender.value))
}
@IBAction func weightSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
}
@IBAction func count(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
func getNumerals(num: Float) -> String {
    
        let number = NSNumber(value: num)
        let format = NumberFormatter()
        format.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar") // You can set locale of your language
        let formatedNumber = format.string(from: number)
        return formatedNumber!
    
    }


}
```

[My application Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5bbe.png)

Comment: What is an "English number" and what is an "Arabic number"?

Comment: I tried your code, the output is a string "٢" with input 1.84, how you get 0.00?

Comment: see below image

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAlr0.png

Answer (score 2):

I tested via codes below

```
let number = NSNumber(value: 1.84)
let format = NumberFormatter()
format.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar") // You can set locale of your language
format.allowsFloats = true
format.numberStyle = .decimal
let formatedNumber = format.string(from: number)
print("\(formatedNumber)")
```

The output is `"١٫٨٤"`, not 0.00 you said.

Comment: see where i get 0.00

Comment: hi @AbdullahAlNoaimi I created a playground and run codes that I showed below, the output was "١٫٨٤".

Comment: but why i cant get the value when i run the application through storyboard :( ?